# How ASP.NET application can copy recently added data from SQL Server database to another similar one on different SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, synchronization

The problem I'm trying to solve:
I have a dev SQL Server database which is mainly used for staging data entry (occasionally it's getting extra table) and when the person using the system (MVC web app) is happy with the data entry made that doesn't break the system can by single click of a button sync that data with live version of the db on different SQL Server. This avoid getting a developer to do the job every time using RedGate SQL Compare application or similar.

The solution that seems to be the right one is using Sync Framework. I'm trying to create a separate Console App that will connect to the databases and exchange the data but this is where I'm getting lost.

So the first question is: is there any simpler approach?
Second question: if I'll continue with this approach and create provisioning processes in the DB does this means it's one way solution?
Third question: any better tutorials than this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx because I can't get this to work on two remote servers?

I have searched for ages but only got confused even more.

I'll appreciate every suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler approach. Have all the data in one database. Then add an extra column to your tables indicating the status of the rows. Have the status as "temporary" or "confirmed" or something to that effect. Only "confirmed" rows should be considered the real data.